# Which ColorFunction should I use to get such a gradient of blue-cyan-green-yellow-orange-red?

Tags: color, visualization

[image: example figure]

### I want to get the effect in the above Figure. Here is my code:

```
Plot3D[Log[
   4*((1 + x)^2)*(0.0065^2)*Log[y]/(3*((1 - 2 x))^2*(0.0267^2)) + 1]/
  Log[y], {x, 0.315, 0.45}, {y, 0, 1}, Mesh -> 50, ImageSize -> 600, 
 AspectRatio -> 0.8, PlotRange -> {0, 20}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 24], 
 AxesStyle -> {Thick, Thick, Thick}, AxesOrigin -> {0.315, 0, 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> {ν, n, l}, MaxRecursion -> 6, ClippingStyle -> None,
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {20, 300}]]
```

Comment: I get the desired color function since you have already specified it with ColorFunction -> "Rainbow" in your code.

Comment: @Kardashev3 It doesn't look like his example images because it is darker and more muted.  See my answer for my best guess as to what Scott wants.

Comment: ah, some materials science at long last ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would like to draw your attention to [`Blend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blend.html), which is very useful for custom gradient coloring. Taken more or less directly from the documention:

```
Graphics[Table[{Blend[{Blue, Cyan, Green, Yellow, Red}, x], 
   Disk[{8 x, 0}]}, {x, 0, 1, 1/8}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You may want to adjust/weigh the blending to your liking - see the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blend.html) for further enlightment.

Answer (score 18):

The color function used is the standard "jet" colormap that is ubiquitous in figures generated using MATLAB. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9321152) (by J. M.) has an exact `ColorFunction` for reproducing the jet colormap:

```
jet[u_?NumericQ] := Blend[
    {{0, RGBColor[0, 0, 9/16]}, {1/9, Blue}, {23/63, Cyan}, {13/21, Yellow},
    {47/63, Orange}, {55/63, Red}, {1, RGBColor[1/2, 0, 0]}}, 
    u] /; 0 <= u <= 1
```

[image]

Comment: Is it just me or does this actually *not* match the original images very well?  Maybe it's the shape of the surface. \*shrug\*

Comment: @Mr.Wizard OP never included a plot of the original image, so it's all in the scaling. If you observe carefully, the colors in my bar legend matches that in OP's examples. I do not think yours (Yves') is correct or that `Glow` is necessary here.

Comment: Yeah, it's the shape of the surface.  This looks right:  `Plot3D[x + y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> (jet[#3] &)]` (+1 of course)

Comment: @rm-rf I was just pointing to `Blend`, no claim to the correct ingredients thereof.

Comment: Somehow, I am now having misgivings for having contributed to "rainbow abuse" in data visualization… :o personally, I only used `jet[]` for artwork, but went with things like `"ThermometerColors"` for actual data visualization.

Comment: @J. M. Don't worry, I [fixed](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/67217/5)  it for you :) Now people have no excuse to not make their own abominations :P

Answer (score 7):

I am betting that you are seeking [`Glow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Glow.html).  Using Yves's gradient in:

*Edit: Looking again at your gradient it is closer to leave out `Green` entirely:*

```
ColorFunction -> (Glow @ Blend[{Blue, Cyan, Yellow, Red}, #3] &)
```

We get:

```
Plot3D[
  Log[4*((1 + x)^2)*(0.0065^2)*Log[y]/(3*((1 - 2 x))^2*(0.0267^2)) + 1]/Log[y], 
  {x, 0.315, 0.45}, {y, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> {0, 20}, Mesh -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 6, 
  ColorFunction -> (Glow @ Blend[{Blue, Cyan, Yellow, Red}, #3] &)
]
```

[image]

Notably the back side remains bright:

[image]

You may also wish to make the ends `Darker`, e.g.:

```
ColorFunction -> (Glow @ 
    Blend[{Darker@Blue, Blue, Cyan, Yellow, Red, Darker@Red}, #3] &)
```

Comment: It is enlightening!tks