# Apply ColorFunction to an Image

Tags: image-processing

is there a faster way to change the colors of an image from grayscale to something like this:

```
Manipulate[coltest2 = (Blend[{{a, Black}, {b, Lighter[Blue, 0.3]}, {c,Lighter[Cyan,0.3]}, {d, White}}, #] &);
Plot[0.2, {x, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> coltest2, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[1]], PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0.5}}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {True, False, None, None}, AspectRatio -> 1/8],
{{a, 0.35}, 0, b, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{b, 0.58}, 0, c, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{c, 0.7}, 0, d, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{d, 0.95}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

than using:

```
Colorize[image,ColorFunction->coltest2]
```

I would like to have the image in the manipulate rather than the sample of the ColorFunction, but Colorize is way to slow for that...

Comment: When the colours you use are fixed for this manipulate, you could create a compiled function which does the blending. This should be fast enough. How big are the images you want to use?

Comment: The images are 1000 x 1000 px, I want to manipulate the blending parameters of the colorfunction, so the colors themselves are fixed.

Comment: How do I create a compiled function to replace colorize? (I hope I got this right - this is the idea?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you can do is, you mimic the behaviour of `Blend` by creating a function that interpolates linearly between colours. What you change with your parameters are the values where the color transitions take place.

Let me give you a simplified example: I use 3 colours. In the compiled function, I only work with their `{r,g,b}` values. As result, I want a compiled function which does the following:

- it takes a parameter `a` between 0 and 1 and a pixel `value` between 0 and 1
- with 3 colours `c1`, `c2` and `c3` it will colorise the pixel: from a pixel value of 0 to `a` it will be colorised with the transition `c1` to `c2`. If the pixel `value` is greater than `a` it will be colorised by blending c2 and c3.
- the compiled function should be able to work in parallel on all pixels of an image

Here is a sample implementation of a function that creates such a colorising compiled function for us:

```
createColorFunc[colors : {_, _, _}] :=
 Function[{c1, c2, c3},
   Compile[{{a, _Real, 0}, {value, _Real, 0}},
    If[value < a,
     c1 + ((-c1 + c2)*value)/a,
     (c3*(a - value) + c2*(-1 + value))/(-1 + a)
     ], Parallelization -> True, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
    ]
   ] @@ List @@@ (ColorConvert[#, "RGB"] & /@ colors)
```

To test is, we load the Lena image in grayscale an build a small `Manipulate`:

```
With[{lena = ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "Grayscale"]},
 Manipulate[
  func = createColorFunc[{c1, c2, c3}];
  Image[func[a, ImageData[lena, "Real"]]],
  {{a, .5}, 0, 1},
  {c1, Black},
  {c2, Gray},
  {c3, White}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You task is now to extend this for more than 3 colours and one color transition position.

Comment: Wow great, thanks a lot! It even has more interactivity than needed, because I will use it with fixed colors.

Comment: @DJJ I think this is what you're looking for: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/67217/5 The question might even be a duplicate.

Comment: Is there some reason to prefer  `Image[ f[ ImageData[image ] ]] ` over `ImageApply[f,image]` ?

Comment: It worked out fine, thanks again. @rm-rf: I think it is not the same question, though it is clearly related.

Comment: follow up: `ImageApply[ func[a, #] & , lena ]` works ok but is a good bit slower.  Also I think pre extracting the imagedata improves this somewhat ( `With[{ idata = ImageData[lena, "Real"] , .... Image[func[a, idata]] .. `

Comment: I have closed this question as a duplicate.  Please (1) tell me if you disagree; (2) consider whether these questions should be merged which will move your answer there (a minor rewrite may be necessary).

Comment: No, I don't disagree and I always trusted your judgement on such things. Nevertheless, I sometimes feel like answering the specific question even if it get's closed because often there is at least some additional information because those answers are (in my case) written up from scratch. About (2): I don't think it is worth the work so I would keep them separated.

Answer (score 4):

While not as fast as halirutan's compiled function, Mr.Wizard's `renderImage` function (from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21488/862)) can be used here with reasonable performance:

```
renderImage[array_?MatrixQ, cf_, opts : OptionsPattern[Image]] := 
 Module[{tbl}, 
  tbl = List @@@ Array[cf[#/2047`] &, 2048, 0] // N // Developer`ToPackedArray;
  Image[tbl[[# + 1]] & /@ Round[2047 array], opts]]

img = ImageData @ ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "Grayscale"];

Manipulate[
 coltest2 = (Blend[{{a, Black}, {b, Lighter[Blue, 0.3]}, {c, Lighter[Cyan, 0.3]}, {d, White}}, #] &);
 renderImage[img, coltest2],
 {{a, 0.35}, 0, b, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 0.58}, 0, c, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c, 0.7}, 0, d, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{d, 0.95}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```