# How to speed up Colorize

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing, color

I have a list of about 500 images similar to the following:

```
A = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bV4O.png"]
```

[image: my image]

```
AbsoluteTiming[Colorize[A, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"]]
```

[image: colorized image]

takes ~ 0.6 seconds, which scales to around 5 minutes for applying the `Colorize` function to my list of 500 images.

In other programs, this general feature of mapping grayscale values to colors is quite fast. I'd like to find a way to speed this up if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Question [71310](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71278/apply-colorfunction-to-an-image/71310) is closely related.

Comment: Although it might not save speed in terms of computation time, you might find `ImageFileApply` to be a useful function, especially when processing a large number of images.

Comment: and finally before this get likely gets locked: `Graphics[Raster[ImageData[A, DataReversed -> True], ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"]]`

Comment: Related: [(21482)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21482/121), [(71278)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71278/121)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is also pretty straightforward to create your own color map. For example, the following code reads in the image, and multiplies each of the color channels by an appropriate factor, then recombines the three into a single color image. It is very fast. Change the constants (in this case, 0, 1, and 0) at will.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bV4O.png"];
rimg = ImageMultiply[img, 0];
gimg = ImageMultiply[img, 1];
bimg = ImageMultiply[img, 0];
ColorCombine[{rimg, gimg, bimg}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

### Approach

As halirutan suggested in [Apply ColorFunction to an Image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71291), we can create a custom, compiled color function and apply it using the trick

```
Image[colorFunction @ ImageData @ img]
```

On my computer with my custom avocado color function, this is more than eight times faster than `Colorize`, taking only 0.035 seconds.

### How to create a fast custom color function

In order to create a faster avocado color function, we first need to find out what colors that color function is based on. Mr. Wizard explains that in his answer to [Is it possible to insert new colour schemes into ColorData?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57893).

```
Position[DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemes, "AvocadoColors", Infinity]
(* Out: {{141, 1, 1}} *)
```

So the colors are given by

```
List @@@ DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`colorSchemes[[141, 5]]
(* Out: {{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0.442859, 0.0749256}, {0.289326, 0.685107, 
  0.108759}, {0.683989, 0.830896, 0.145815}, {1., 0.984375, 0.230411}} *)
```

So we've got five different colors. Just like halirutan, I will do a linear interpolation between these colors which is what `Blend` does, which is what `Colorize` uses (thanks J. M. for debugging help to make it work perfectly). I'm also using the `Parallelization` and `Listable` settings like halirutan to make the function fast. I also added `CompilationTarget -> "C"` which improves the speed even more.

```
avocadoColors = Compile[value, Module[{c1, c2, c3, c4, c5},
   c1 = {0., 0., 0.};
   c2 = {0., 0.442859, 0.0749256};
   c3 = {0.289326, 0.685107, 0.108759};
   c4 = {0.683989, 0.830896, 0.145815};
   c5 = {1., 0.984375, 0.230411};
   Which[
    value < 0.25, c1 + (c2 - c1) (value/0.25),
    value < 0.5, c2 + (c3 - c2) ((value - 0.25)/0.25),
    value < 0.75, c3 + (c4 - c3) ((value - 0.5)/0.25),
    True, c4 + (c5 - c4) ((value - 0.75)/0.25)
    ]
   ],
  Parallelization -> True,
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
  CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ]
```

You can now test this using

```
Image[avocadoColors @ ImageData @ img]
```

Comment: "…even though that may not be exactly what `ColorData["AvocadoColors"]` does…" - `Blend[]` actually does linear interpolation, last time I checked, so the compiled version ought to be equivalent.

Comment: @J.M. I added an image that compares the final result between `Colorize` and the custom color function.

Comment: That darkening certainly is odd. What happens if you do `Colorize[img, ColorFunction -> (RGBColor @@ avocadoColors[#] &)]`?

Comment: @J.M. That is the same as `Image[avocadoColors@ImageData@img]`.

Comment: I mean, in that case, there is also no darkening when you execute it? (I'm thinking about whether the darkening is due to `Blend[]` or `Colorize[]` or something else entirely.

Comment: @J.M. I got you, but no it was the same as when I didn't use `Colorize` i.e. no darkening. So the problem should be in `Blend`.

Comment: As I see it, `ColorData["AvocadoColors"] /@ Range[0, 1, 1/20]` and `RGBColor @@@ avocadoColors[Range[0, 1, 1/20]]` should give identical outputs. Do they?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23974/discussion-between-pickett-and-guess-who-it-is).

Comment: I think I understand the difference now; the increments should be 0.25 instead of 0.2; if these are changed, there should no longer be any difference.

Answer (score 7):

This answer is effectively a generalization of the approach by halirutan and Pickett. Here, I present a function that when given a list of colors, a list of positions and colors, or a color gradient known to `ColorData[]`, it yields a listable compiled function effectively equivalent to `Blend[]`:

```
makeCompiledBlend[colors : (_String | _List), opts___] :=
      Module[{cl = colors, sg},
             If[StringQ[cl], cl = ColorData[cl, "BlendArgument"]];
             If[! ListQ[cl], Return[$Failed]];
             If[! VectorQ[cl],
                {sg, cl} = Transpose[SortBy[cl, {First}]],
                sg = Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[cl] - 1)]];
             cl = (List @@ ColorConvert[#, RGBColor]) & /@ cl;
             With[{compileBody = Which @@ Riffle[Append[
                   Thread[\[FormalX] < ArrayPad[DeleteDuplicates[sg], -1]], 
                   True],
                   With[{u = (\[FormalX] - #1)/(#2 - #1)}, {1 - u, u}.#3] & @@@ 
                   DeleteCases[Append @@@ First[
                               Partition[{sg, cl}, {2, 2}, 1]],
                               {Repeated[x_?NumericQ, {2}], __}]]}, 
                  Compile[{{\[FormalX], _Real}}, compileBody, opts,
                           RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
                           RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]]]
```

Thus,

```
myAvocadoColors = makeCompiledBlend["AvocadoColors"];
Image[myAvocadoColors[ImageData[img]]]
```

should yield the expected image. I had omitted the option settings `CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True` in this version, but you can add them in if you wish.