# Mapping colours to numbers

Tags: color, inverse

Through this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67212/modify-existing-color-scheme/67217#67217) I've learned how to make a function to map a colour gradient to an interval of numbers like

```
redblue = 
Blend[Transpose[{{0.5, 4.1`}, {RGBColor[0.986145, 0, 0.0272526], 
  RGBColor[0, 0.0310826, 0.516304]}}], #1] &
```

I tried by reversing the Transpose to create a function to do the very opposite...put in an `RGBColor` between the original limits and get a number. However it failed miserably.

```
num = Transpose[{{0.5, 4.1`}, {RGBColor[0.986145, 0, 0.0272526], 
 RGBColor[0, 0.0310826, 0.516304]}}] &
```

**How would one create a function to map `RGBColor` to a number?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inversecolorfunc[color_RGBColor, function_] := Module[
  {cd},
  cd[val_Real] := 
   ColorDistance[color, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][val]];
  ReplaceAll[
   x,
   Last@NMinimize[{cd[x], 0 <= x <= 1}, {x}]
   ]]

inversecolorfunc[RandomColor[], ColorData["TemperatureMap"]]
(* 0.0684286 *)

inversecolorfunc[RandomColor[], redblue]
(* 0.330163 *)
```

Comment: Ah, the function works nicely, though it doesn't retreive a value from the original boundries of 0.5 to 4.1 in redblue....rather only between 0 and 1,

Comment: @morbo  By default, color gradients have a single parameter that ranges from 0 to 1. You can easily modify the domain `NMinimize[{cd[x], 0,5 <= x <= 4.1}, {x}]`