# How to set the same scaling for multiple density plots while using the ColorBar package or user-defined colorfunction?

Tags: plotting, color, packages

I know questions with this theme have been asked before, and the one-line answer to them is-

"Use `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`"

But my specific concern is the same scaling for tweaked colour themes using the [ColorBar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/67217/78049) package or some self-defined colour functions using the `Blend` option in Mathematica.

Let me provide an example below to explain my problem:

Suppose I have the following Mathematica code:

```
bl = BarLegend[{"GreenPinkTones", {-10, 10}}];

dp1 = DensityPlot[Sin[x] + y, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"GreenPinkTones", {-10, 10}}], 
   ImageSize -> Medium];

dp2 = DensityPlot[Sin[x] + 3 y, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"GreenPinkTones", {-10, 10}}], 
   ImageSize -> Medium];

Legended[Row[{dp1, dp2}, Spacer[2]], bl]
```

which gives me a common colour scale for both the plots with a common legend as below:

[image: colorbar1]

Now if I tweak my code using the **ColorBar** package, like this:

First, I load the package and define a newly tweaked colour theme:

```
Needs["ColorBar`"]
    
newtheme = Setting@ColorBar["GreenPinkTones"];
```

where I use  "Evaluate in place" or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> after selecting `ColorBar["GreenPinkTones"]` on my Windows machine, which gives me the option to tweak some colours, like the one I provided here:

[image: newtheme]

Now, I proceed as below:

```
bl = BarLegend[{newtheme, {-10, 10}}];

dp1 = DensityPlot[Sin[x] + y, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> {newtheme, {-10, 10}}, ImageSize -> Medium];

dp2 = DensityPlot[Sin[x] + 3 y, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> {newtheme, {-10, 10}}, ImageSize -> Medium];

Legended[Row[{dp1, dp2}, Spacer[2]], bl]
```

which gives me some warning messages and the following output:

[image: colorbar2]

Where am I making a mistake? What changes should I make in my code to make it work?

Any help in this regard would be beneficial!

Comment: You're not making a mistake. I think the right place to add this flexibility would be in the `ColorBar` package. 0-1 range is hardcoded in, whereas it should accept a min/max parameter and use `ColorData[{gradient, {min, max}}]` to do the rescaling (and replace all other 0/1 with min/max). As a short-term solution, I probably would've added `/.{x__?NumericQ}:>Rescale[{x},{0,1},{-10,10}]` on the line defining `newtheme` just so that I don't have to worry about the number of control points. But until the package is updated, either this or your solution is fine.

Comment: @rm-rf thanks for providing a short-term solution. I hope you can update the package soon. It's really helpful indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a manual way to do this, but it's quite tedious:

1. Make a newly tweaked colour scheme:

[image: newcolortheme]

2. Change the range of your chosen theme according to your needs:

```
newtheme[[1, 1, 1, 1]] = Range[-10, 10, 20/15];
```

3. Now, make some adjustments to the previous code:

```
bl = BarLegend[{newtheme[#] &, {-10, 10}}];

dp1 = DensityPlot[Sin[x] + y, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> newtheme, 
   ImageSize -> Medium];

dp2 = DensityPlot[Sin[x] + 3 y, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> newtheme, 
   ImageSize -> Medium];

Legended[Row[{dp1, dp2}, Spacer[2]], bl]
```

which gives the desired result:

[image: colorbar3]

I hope others can provide better solutions to make this process automated and more efficient!

**Edit:** Thanks to [@rm -rf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/rm-rf), the developer  of the package for providing a better solution in the comments:

```
newtheme = 
 Setting@ColorBar["GreenPinkTones"] /. {x__?NumericQ} :> 
   Rescale[{x}, {0, 1}, {-10, 10}]
```